# Is it safe to use parallel execution policies with std::back_inserter?

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to know whether using execution policies `std::execution::par` and `std::execution::par_unseq` is safe when the output is `std::back_insert_iterator`. For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> src(100, "test"), dst;
std::move(std::execution::par_unseq, src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));
```

Is it guaranteed that no concurrent insertions will be made to the destination vector?

Comment: *When using parallel execution policy, it is the programmer's responsibility to avoid data races and deadlocks* [taken from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).

Comment: It is not safe, as you expect with STL containers.

Comment: the algorithm is not aware of the fact that the iterator inserts elements to the container. From pov of the algorithm its just an iterator that allows to access elements.

Comment: The parallel algorithms in `<algorithm>` expect forward iterators, which `std::back_insert_iterator` is not. So it's not just unsafe. It's outright prohibited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `push_back` on a `std::vector` does not match the requirements of `par_unseq` or `par`.

So no, it isn't safe.

By saying `par` you are promising that access to the iterators used for input and output contains no race conditions.  That fails here.

`par_unseq` requires **more** promises from you; basically that you are both data-race free, **and** your algorithm is suitable for vectorization (doing things in batches).

`push_back` does not qualify, and `back_inserter` is defined in terms of `push_back`.

On the other hand:

```
std::vector<std::string> src(100, "test"), dst(100, "");
std::move(std::execution::par_unseq, src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin());
```

this is valid, because you are allowed to parallel and concurrently access individual elements of a `vector` (except `vector<bool>`)